# Reset zoom on svg with d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I can zoom the svg as I want it to, now i try to reset it if the user does a doubble click on the div the D3Map (svg) is rendered to.

I already know that it's done with 'zoom.transform(svg, yd3.zoomIdentit);' somehow, but i always get an error:

> zoom.transform is not a function

Where and what do I have to add the missing?

The call I make:

```
$('.worldmap').bind('dblclick', function() {
        zoom.transform(svg, d3.zoomIdentit);
});
```

The zoom code:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", function () {
               let scale = d3.event.scale;
               g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate.join(",") + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
               g.selectAll("circle")
                    .attr("r", 3 / scale)
                    .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
               g.selectAll("path")
                    .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
        });

svg.call(zoom)
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
    .on("mousedown.zoom", null)
    .on("touchstart.zoom", null)
    .on("touchmove.zoom", null)
    .on("touchend.zoom", null);
```

Comment: Your question uses `d3.zoomIdentit`, is this the case with your actual code?

Comment: in my actual code I don't use it. Could that also cause the problem with 'zoom.transform ' or is this an other misstake